# How to merge stereo video?

Tags: opencv, camera, virtual-reality, stereo-3d, video-editing

I recently purchased a stereo USB camera to capture some footage through my AR headset. Now the camera records through 2 lenses and gives 2 outputs: a left and a right video feed. My goal is to combine the left and right video feed into a single mono output.

Here is a picture of the camera and the [link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07F6X8YML) to the exact model.
[image]

Here is a screenshot of the video output:
[image]

As you can see I want to somehow interlace those 2 videos into 1 (I guess similar to anaglyph) so it can be viewed on a 2d screen (without a vr headset). Does anyone know any software programs that can do this? Or has anyone written a custom script?

Comment: what exactly do you expect on the 2d screen? Do you want to get a 3d impression, or just showing both images in a single frame (e.g. blended or with wrong colors)?

Comment: I want both images to be interlaced (blended) into a single frame

Comment: separate both images (e.g. subimages) then use out = 0.5*A + 0.5*B for blending. Or create a mask where you write 255 in every second row and use B.copyTo(A, mask) for interlacing

Comment: If I am not wrong, you want those 2 view to be same. Probably, those are for different purposes. The cameras are not in the same place so it would be a really difficult or impossible